# Can I qualify an injection based on an Enum?

Tags: java, spring, enums, spring-3

We have some legacy code that I'm trying to figure out a way to clean up. One solution I've thought of is that perhaps I can inject a custom handler based on the enum value I'm given. Can I qualify an Injection based on an enum? I'm thinking something like this maybe (pseudocode)

```
@Service(MyEnum.MYVALUE, MyEnum.MYOTHERVALUE) // produces a handler given these enums
public class MyHandler { ... }

@Service(MyEnum.ANOTHERVALUE)
public class AnotherHandler {... }

// .... some mystical way of telling spring what my current enum context is so I can get the right handler
```

Comment: You can find an example of custom qualifier from the link below https://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring_custom_qualifier_annotation  (Section:  Custom Qualifier with value() Method using Java Configuration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this will work.

First of all, the `value` for a [`@Service`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html) is a `String`, not an `Enum[]`. And, it just suggests a name for the bean that gets registered for that service class.

Instead, what I think you may want is to use is [`@Qualifier`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html). So, you can either have something like:

```
@Service
@Qualifier("foo")
public class FooHandler implements IHandler { ... }

@Service
@Qualifier("bar")
public class BarHandler implements IHandler { ... }

@Component
public class MyThing {
    @Autowired @Qualifier("foo")
    private IHandler handler;

    ...
}
```

Or, you can create your own custom qualifier annotation, like:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Qualifier
public @interface MyQualifier { ... }

@Service
@MyQualifier
public class FooHandler implements IHandler { ... }

@Component
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired @MyQualifier
    private IHandler handler;

    ...
}
```

See [Fine-tuning annotation-based autowiring with qualifiers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) for more details.

Comment: wasn't really suggesting that the `@Service` parameter was an enum, that's why I said "pseudocode", I wasn't sure what the code I was looking for was

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try to create your own validation (yes, even with enums) and then provide your own BeanPostProcessor that will do the job and inject values to your annotated fields.

There are a lot of Spring BeanPostProcessors so you can see how it is done just by browsing Spring's sources.